# IP address of Azure API App and how to restrict IPs

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

I have deployed API App written in Java Servlet.

What I want to know is, that IP address of my API App and the way to allow requests from only one or two IP addresses meaning I want to restrict every IPs except for those.

seems like IP addresses are shared once i deploy several APPs in one region.

anyway please give me some advice : )

Answer (score 3):

There is a range of ip addresses that can be used by azure web apps - basically you are having your site hosted in a web farm that is on a vnet managed by Microsoft.   Microsoft do publish the addresses but they are also subject to change.   Found the link [discovering outgoing ip addresses from azure web sites](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fd53afb7-14b8-41ca-bfcb-305bdeea413e/maintenance-notice-upcoming-changes-to-increase-capacity-for-outbound-network-calls?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) here and it says you can now get this information directly from your portal pages.

For the other question, if you want to protect your services or apps so they can only be called from specific up addresses or ranges, you can continue to use web apps in azure and use IPFilters in the web.config, or use App Service Environments (a private web server farm on your own vnet) and setup network security groups to control traffic;  or host in a VM where you can combine ip filters, nsgs and Windows firewall if you want!

IP Filtering for Java based apps (Tomcat): see [server fault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/614265/how-would-i-create-a-ip-whitelist-for-tomcat)

IP filtering in web.config (.net based apps): see [this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/)

```
<security>
    <!-- deny everybody -->
   <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
        <!-- "clear" removes all upstream restrictions -->
       <clear/>
       <<!-- permit the loopback address  -->
       <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true"/>
        <!--permit network 83.116.119.0 to 83.116.119.255-->
       <add ipAddress="83.116.119.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" allowed="true"/>
   </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

Comment: Thank you for great guidance. Could you please tell me where should web.config file be located in? "web.config files located in their website." doesn't sound clear to me haha...

Comment: web.config file, isn't it config file of .NET ? even mine is Servlet, do i need to have web.config file and is that possible? i put into wwwroot folder and got error : )

Comment: Hi MyoungSoo - yes you're right I missed the java servlet piece - that means you'd be hosted by either Tomcat or Jetty (whichever one you chose when you setup the web app).  I've added this to the answer: IP Filtering for Java based apps (Tomcat): see [server fault answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/614265/how-would-i-create-a-ip-whitelist-for-tomcat)

Comment: Thanx for answering Russell !, even i added filter tag into my Web.xml file it doesn't work : ) hahaha... it allows every IPs

Comment: Are you using tomcat or jetty?

Comment: Tomcat and i deployed Tomcat from Azure portal UI so seems like i can't see the tomcat resources(files) from my API App file System. just telling you : )

Comment: I feel like that i found the problem ... but dont know why it happened and how to fix it... i specified the Filter class on the Web.xml and programmatically i'm restricting IPs now, anyway, wherever i request, the requested IP address is 127.0.0.1... why is it like this : (

Comment: Ok seems like IP addr of client is involved in "X-Forwarded-For" header...

Comment: But still have question : ) now i can see the right Client IP addr but "x.x.x.x:18944" there is random port num? after IP addr ... what is happening? do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you looking at the client IP by displaying it from your web servlet?  I'm guessing that it's showing you the translated ip address once it's gone from the public ip through the load balancer on top of your web instances.

Comment: even in the "X-Forwarded-For" header there are two duplicated IP addresses like "x.x.x.x:1234, x.x.x.x:1234" ... got confused really haha...

Comment: but the client ip addresses match where you're calling from?

Comment: yes it is, i just added codes to split by "," and take out after ":" to get IP

Comment: yeah : - ) kinda...? Thank you very much and sorry for being late to say this