# How to limit services to be used from same website

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, webapi2

I'm new to azure, and I'm trying to setup a single page website(web api 2). How can I limit access to my services so only my website can use it?

I know that I can use app services to setup my web applications/services but as far as i understand it will be open to everyone.

I also read about APIs, but Api management service seems very expensive and advanced for such a simple task. Is there any options? Am I in the wrong track?

---

**Update**

Ok, I saw the link for filtering based on IP. But as I've mentioned that single page application also is hosted on Azure. There is no static IP. If that is the way, I still need to know how you will find out about the IPRange.

Comment: Please comment if you down vote, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906500/ip-address-of-azure-api-app-and-how-to-restrict-ips

Comment: @CSharpRocks I wonder how would you find the ip address of the Azure cloud to put in the web config

Comment: As I know Azure WebApp doesn't provide a static outbound IP address unless an SSL cert with the WebApp is tied to an inbound IP address.

Answer (score 1):

App Service to use different authentication providers [Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication),[Facebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication),[Google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication),[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication),[Twitter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-twitter-authentication).
We can set any type of Authentication/Authorization in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/).More info about how to use authentication for API Apps in Azure App Service, please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-dotnet-user-principal-auth).

[image]